# Applying code for one file to multiple files python (Newbie Question)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, file

I wrote the following code that takes a column from a csv file, it then converts it into an integer and adds them all up. I have done this for only one file and I have around 80 files to apply the same code to.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
columns = defaultdict(list)
with open('Team11BoM.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for (k,v) in row.items():
            if k not in columns:
                columns[k] = list()
            columns[k].append(v)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Team11BoM.csv")

b = list(df['Reported Price'])
a = list(df['Actual Price'])

for i in range(0, len(a)):
    a[i] = int(float(a[i]))

v = sum(a)
print("the total actual cost(s) for team 11 is:", v)

for i in range(0, len(b)):
    b[i] = int(float(b[i]))

h = sum(b)
print("the total reported price for team 11 is:", h)
```

it prints out the following:

```
the total actual cost(s) for team 11 is: 945
the total reported price for team 11 is: 707
```

I want it to print out:

```
the total actual cost(s) for *filename* is: *Total cost of that team*
the total reported price for *filename* is: *Total reported price of that team*
```

Is there any simple way to do this?

thanks,
Irfan S.

Comment: I added an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

files_dir = 'csv'

csv_files = os.listdir(files_dir)
print(csv_files)

def convert_to_int(file_name):
    file_name = f'{files_dir}/{file_name}'
    columns = defaultdict(list)
    with open(file_name) as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            for (k,v) in row.items():
                if k not in columns:
                    columns[k] = list()
                columns[k].append(v)

    df = pd.read_csv(file_name)

    b = list(df['Reported Price'])
    a = list(df['Actual Price'])

    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        a[i] = int(float(a[i]))

    v = sum(a)
    print("the total actual cost(s) for team 11 is:", v)

    for i in range(0, len(b)):
        b[i] = int(float(b[i]))

    h = sum(b)
    print("the total reported price for team 11 is:", h)

for file in csv_files:
    convert_to_int(file)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late question but, I replaced the FOLDER_PATH with the file name but it gave me a `TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike, integer or None, not module` also, I put the file name without the quotes in the code, Is there something more that I need to change/add? thanks!

Comment: No you should only configure the Folder path, What line does the console show the error at?

Comment: full error is: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "location of file", line 6, in <module>
    csv_files = os.listdir(csv)
TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike, integer or None, not module
` I put the file name into the code like this `csv_files = os.listdir(csv)`

Comment: os.listdir()  takes the folder name as a string so you should do it like this os.listdir('csv') if you folder name is csv.

Comment: even with the quotes around the folder csv (`csv_files = os.listdir('csv')`) it gives two errors:`Traceback (most recent call last):   File "file location", line 37, in <module>     convert_to_int(file) ` and `File "file location", line 11, in convert_to_int     with open(file_name) as f: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Team41BoM.csv'`

Comment: some of the files are not formatted correctly–they have letters instead of number and some have empty columns–could this be the reason that it is giving me the error? Thanks!

Comment: The problem was an error with the file path, for example it must be csv/Team41BoM.csv and not Team41BoM.csv, anyways I edited my code try the new one!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219769/discussion-between-irfan-s-and-janinirami).

Answer (score 1):

First, you should define a function that you can reuse to avoid code repetition.

```py
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

def process_file(file_name):
    columns = defaultdict(list)
    with open(file_namename) as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            for (k,v) in row.items():
                if k not in columns:
                    columns[k] = list()
                columns[k].append(v)

    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name)

    b = list(df['Reported Price'])
    a = list(df['Actual Price'])

    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        a[i] = int(float(a[i]))

    v = sum(a)
    print(f"the total actual cost(s) for {file_name} 11 is:", v)

    for i in range(0, len(b)):
        b[i] = int(float(b[i]))

    h = sum(b)
    print(f"the total reported price for {file_name} 11 is:", h)
```

Second, call this function and iterate over the list of files:

```py
# assuming all of this files are in the current directory

list_of_files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
for file_name in list_of_files:
    process_file(file_name)
```

Comment: For the list of files, am I supposed to put all of the csvs into a folder?

Comment: @IrfanS, assuming that all files are in the same directory you can use `files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]` in order to get the list of files to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use for loop and iterate over each file in the cwd and do the same with all, Make sure all files are in the same directory**

```py
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
import os

def valueSum(filename):
    columns = defaultdict(list)
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            for (k,v) in row.items():
                if k not in columns:
                    columns[k] = list()
                columns[k].append(v)

    df = pd.read_csv(filename)

    b = list(df['Reported Price'])
    a = list(df['Actual Price'])

    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        a[i] = int(float(a[i]))

    v = sum(a)

    for i in range(0, len(b)):
        b[i] = int(float(b[i]))

    h = sum(b)

    print("the total actual cost(s) for team 11 is:", v)
    print("the total reported price for team 11 is:", h)

for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"): #count only csv files
        valueSum(filename)
```

Comment: I got the error.     'ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer'  I think it is giving this error beause some file might not have the same format. Im not sure what a NaN is either.

Comment: thats because some value in your csv file is NaN. Make a check if its not NaN then convert to int

Comment: Im not sure how to do that, is the some sort of a function that I can use?

Comment: you can do that with `math.isnan()`, `math.isnan(value)` will return True if its NaN and False if its not NaN

Answer (score 0):

How about placing csvs in one directory and perfom loop like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
def summer(f):
    name = f.split('.')[0]
    df = pd.read_csv(f)

    b = list(df['Reported Price'])
    a = list(df['Actual Price'])

    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        a[i] = int(float(a[i]))

    v = sum(a)
    print(f"the total actual cost(s) for {name} is:", v)

    for i in range(0, len(b)):
        b[i] = int(float(b[i]))

    h = sum(b)
    print("the total reported price for {name} is:", h)

path = 'path/to/csv-files/directory/'

import os
for fil in os.listdir(path):
    summer(fil)
```

Comment: Im using iCloud Drive and when I put the path it says "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'iCloud Drive/desktop/IACCproject1'" is this a problem with iCloud drive or something else?

Comment: iCloud drive is at: /home/yourusername/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/